# Get section of the config with no module associated with it

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I can get the config for this:

```
  config :my_app, MyApp.Endpoint,
    url: [host: "localhost"],
    secret_key_base: "fdsfdsfd",
    # ..............
```

this way

```
cfg = Application.get_env(:my_app, MyApp.Endpoint)
```

How can I get this config section:

```
  config :my_app,
    a: 123,
    b: 456
    # ..............
```

For there's no such a function:

```
cfg = Application.get_env(:my_app) # no such function
```

Comment: `Application.get_env(:my_app, :a)` or `Application.get_env(:my_app, :b)`

Comment: @TheAnh I want the whole section and not an individual variable

Comment: Give it a name and you can get it. Let's say. `config :my_app, key,
    a: 123,
    b: 456
Application.get_env(:my_app, key)`

Comment: @TheAnh then it'll break the current functionality

Comment: What do you mean? can you edit your question with expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Application.get_all_env/1`. With

```
config :my_app,
  a: 123,
  b: 456
```

the output I get is:

```
iex(1)> Application.get_all_env(:my_app)
[b: 456, a: 123]
```

Edit: if you want to ignore all configuration where the key is an Elixir module name, you can do this:

```
Application.get_all_env(:my_app)
|> Enum.reject(fn {key, value} ->
  is_atom(key) && Atom.to_string(key) |> String.starts_with?("Elixir.")
end)
|> IO.inspect
```

Comment: will it also read config data of `MyApp.Endpoint` along with it?

Comment: Yes, it will include that.

Comment: i need only `config :my_app,` and nothing else

Comment: `config :my_app, a: 123` is the same as `config :my_app, :a, 123`. They're stored in the same place.

Comment: what's unclear? `cfg = Application.get_env(:my_app, MyApp.Endpoint
` returns everything under `:my_app, MyApp.Endpoint`. I need the same thing but for the section with the name of a module

Comment: You can't know if something was set with `config :my_app, a: 123` or `config :my_app, :a, 123` because they're stored in the same way.

Comment: correction --> *I need the same thing but for the section **without** the name of a module *

Comment: I've added some code to exclude keys which are Elixir module names. Is this what you want?

Comment: maybe. but isn't there a standard way, without those hacks?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code? The thing you want seems to be a hack because like I said both the styles end up being stored identically. You can't know if it was set with 2 commas or 1 comma and keyword list.

Comment: I'm asking about the module name vs its absence! Why do you keep talking about the keyword list!

Comment: Because `:a` is a valid module name. Try running `defmodule :a do end`.